# Using a USB 3 port as a power delivery port for quicker charging of connected devices

Tags: usb, charging

My Android phone charges via a USB 2 micro-usb connector and is capable of charging at greater than the 500mA provided by USB 2 data mode.

Is it possible to configure my Mac so that its USB 3 port functions in USB-2 power delivery mode and can thus deliver power at greater than 500mA?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#PD-R2.0V1.0

Answer (score 1):

You are right. USB3 could do that, but needs a partner USB of same family to do it.

Thus the USB2 would be the bottleneck.

However the USB2 already can handle up to maximum of 900mW.

> Devices can request higher currents and supply voltages from compliant
>   hosts.

In simple way, if your Android makes the correct request it could get up to 900mW supplied. You can check how much it gets in the About this Mac.

read more here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5581/77190

and here:https://superuser.com/q/293189

Comment: Hmm... System Report says "Current Available (mA): 500".  So my phone apparently needs to be given the impression that it's connected in Power Supply mode, as if it were connected to an AC adapter.  Or it needs to be connected to something other than my Mac, or with some sort of intermediary device.